# What is the impact of a big object lookup to a Standard/Custom Object?

Tags: big-object, data-model

Say I have a data model where an Big Object where I want to store an Account Id. Is it better to store the 18 char Id as Text, or actually make the lookup relationship so the big object looks up to the account? In the latter approach, do things like skew, record locking, or anything else come into play?